# linux usb gadgets traffic monitoring

Tags: linux, debugging, usb, accessory

I am using a BeagleBone Black board (kernel 4.14.108-ti-r104) to create USB gadget using configfs/functionfs. I compose my gadget (using gadgettool) providing details about device configuration (function, vendor id, product id and ton of other params), run my userspace program that writes descriptors and strings to `ep0` and connect the device to host. All works fine, I get BIND (when binding device to UDC) and ENABLE (when actually host is connected) events and my device can read from `ep2` and write to `ep1`. Using wireshark I see the communication looks good, device and configuration descriptors as well as strings are exchanged.

The problem starts when I connect the device to another host. Unfortunately I have almost no control over that host, in particular I cannot run wireshark there, I don't even know the OS. The only thing I can do is to plug/unplug device, optionally see a message that device was detected and optionally a restart. What I see on the gadget side is that following BIND and ENABLE events I immediately get SUSPEND event and read on `ep2` fails with 108 (ESHUTDOWN). Now the question is how to track the problem down.

I tried usbmon, but it seems it does not listen to traffic when device is in gadget mode. I have also seen `https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/gadget/udc/trace.h` file which seems to define some udc trace points, but I am not really sure how they can be used.

So the final question is simple: how do I get any information about traffic on USB bus having access only to gadget side? I don't need full trace, but al least some information which packets were exchanged  would be super useful. Did it fail while exchanging device descriptors, configuration/interface/endpoint descriptors or strings or something totally different?

Small update:
The whole thing is about Android Open Accessory Protocol and I am trying to write a gadget that would connect to this accessory.

I have changed my gadget composition somewhat and now I know the gadget is being identified by host (it displays manufacturer/model) so I suppose the issue is not in device descriptor and strings. I have used two additional flags in descriptors (`FUNCTIONFS_ALL_CTRL_RECIP` | `FUNCTIONFS_CONFIG0_SETUP`) and when connecting to my computer I get setup event (request 51 as expected), but when connecting to my accessory I still get SUSPEND/ESHUTDOWN. This time though it looks like the time between ENABLE and SUSPEND is much greater (over 10 seconds) which looks to me as if the host send some message, but this message was not processed by my gadget and then the host timeout out and disabled usb device. Still don't know how to find out if the accessory sent anything to gadget and what it was...

Comment: There is no easy way to do it, as far as I know. You have to use [usbmon](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt). Where you use `usbmon` is your choice. You may be able to use a breakout box to tap the signal for debugging, but I have no experience with it. Also see [How to log USB modem data for a specific device?](http://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2019-November/020444.html) on the Kernel Newbies mailing list.

Comment: The breakout boxes for USB 2.0 are quite pricey :-( And as for usbmon I don't really have any choice: on my gadget usbmon does not work and I do not have access to usb host.

Comment: @TomaszGrobelny, were you ever able to figure this out? I'm also seeing a similar behavior with something I'm doing with an Android Accessory.

Comment: No, probably heavy modification of usbmon would be needed to get it working.